# Error con MVC en PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar MVC y tengo un error que es el siguiente:

> Notice: Undefined property: Nuevo::$model in C:\xampp\htdocs\pmvc\controllers\nuevo.php on line 15

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\pmvc\controllers\nuevo.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pmvc\libs\app.php(29): Nuevo->nuevoAlumno() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\pmvc\index.php(10): App->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pmvc\controllers\nuevo.php on line 15

controllers\nuevo.php

```
<?php

class Nuevo extends Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->view->render('nuevo/index');
}

function nuevoAlumno(){
    $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];

    if($this->model->insert([
        'matricula'     => $matricula,
        'nombre'        => $nombre,
        'apellido'      => $apellido
    ])){
        echo 'Nuevo alumno creado';
    }
}
}

?>
```

libs\app.php

```
<?php

require_once 'controllers/err.php';

class App{

function __construct(){
    
    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url']: Null;
    $url = rtrim($url, '/');
    $url = explode('/', $url);

    if(empty($url[0])){
        $archiboController = 'controllers/main.php';
        require_once $archiboController;
        $controller = new Main();
        $controller->loadModel('main');
        return false;
    }

    $archiboController = 'controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';

    if(file_exists($archiboController)){
        require_once $archiboController;
        $controller = new $url[0];
        $controller->loadModel($url[0]);

        if(isset($url[1])){
            $controller->{$url[1]}();
        }
    } else {
        $controller = new Err();
    }

}
}

?>
```

libs\controller.php

```
<?php

class Controller{

function __construct(){
    $this->view = new View();
}

function loadModel($model){
    $url = 'models/'.$model.'model.php';

    if(file_exists($url)){
        require $url;

        $modelName = $model.'Model';
        $this->model = new $modelName();
    }
}
}

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'libs/db.php';
require_once 'libs/controller.php';
require_once 'libs/view.php';
require_once 'libs/model.php';
require_once 'libs/app.php';

require_once 'conff/conff.php';

$app = new App();
?>
```

nuevo/index.php

```
<?php require 'views/header.php'; ?>
<div class="main">
<h1 class="title">Nuevo</h1>

<form action="<?=constant('URL');?>nuevo/nuevoAlumno" method="POST">
<p>
<label for="matricula">Matricula</label><br>
<input type="text" name="matricula" id="matricula" autocomplete="off" required>
</p>
<p>
<label for="nombre">Nombre</label><br>
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" autocomplete="off" required>
</p>
<p>
<label for="apellido">Apellido</label><br>
<input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" autocomplete="off" required>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Registrar">
</p>
</form>
</div>
<?php require 'views/foot.php'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

La clase Nuevo esta definida, pero no se como solucionarlo.
Agradezco de antemano!

Comment: Hola. $model no ha sido declarado entre los atributos de la clase Controller. Debes declarar `protected $model;` de modo que `$this->model = new $modelName();` apunta a un atributo existente. Analogamente, no veo que $view esté declarado.

Comment: Entiendo, pero al tratar de agregar sigue este error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\pmvc\controllers\nuevo.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pmvc\libs\app.php(29): Nuevo->nuevoAlumno() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\pmvc\index.php(10): App->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pmvc\controllers\nuevo.php on line 15`

Comment: No veo definido el método insert(). Controller no lo tiene y no está extendiendo una clase que lo tenga. Estás seguro que la clase cuyo nombre se construye para ser instanciada en $this->model=nwe $modelName(); lo implementa?

Comment: A ver empezando por el error, en la clase `Nuevo` haces uso de `$this->model->insert()` pero dicha clase no tiene ninguna propiedad `model`. Si el modelo es una dependencia se la debes de pasar, bien en el constructor o bien al llamar al método. Extiendes de `Controller` pero en ninguno de los constructores llamas al método que tienes para cargar el modelo `loadModel()`

Comment: ¿A qué clase pertenece el método `insert()`? Es lo que te está dando problemas. Parecería que es un método de la clase `Model`, por la forma en que lo llamas, pero dicha clase no tiene ese método. Entonces, ¿a qué clase pertenece?

Comment: Gracias y la verdad es que estoy siguiendo el tutorial y voy a verlo nuevamente porque no estoy entendiendo nada. De seguro debe ser facil lo que me dice, pero cada linea que toco es un error tras otro. Les agradezco de todos modos y perdon mi ignorancia. Pero voy a resolverlo cueste lo que cueste!

Answer (score 0):

En la función loadModel, en la línea que dice:

```
$this->model = new $ModelName();
```

Debes reemplazarlo así:

```
$model = new $ModelName();
```

Puesto que estas declarando el valor de un parametro ($model es parametro de loadModel) y no una variable de la clase (clase "Nuevo") en si.

Comment: Gracias lepeman, pero sigue el mismo error. Edite la pregunta y agregue el index de nuevo.